# Catching where an Image fails to load from a src url

Tags: javascript, html, image

I need to load images in a webpage dynamically in Javascript, but need to catch if any image fails to load, how can I do this?
For instance:

```
try{
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "404_not_found.png";
} catch( err ) {
  // tried this but didn't work
}
```

Yes, I know I'm not even waiting for the image to `onload` but when a 404 occurs, the onload method doesn't get called anyway.

Answer (score 13):

Before you assign the `.src` property, you need to set `onload`, `onerror`, and `onabort` handler functions.  And, you may want to also set a timer so you can assume it isn't going to load if none of the handlers have been called when the timer fires.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/48JmQ/

```
var img = new Image();
img.onerror = function() {alert("error")};
img.onabort = function() {alert("abort")};
img.onload = function() {alert("success")};
img.src = "404_not_found.png";
```